# Validation rule on user detail record to make phone number field required but only for certain profiles

Tags: validation-rule

I can't seem to get my validation rule to work.

I need a Validation rule on user detail record to make phone number field required but only for certain profiles. I need the number to be in the format for UK numbers e.g 0207 456 7689 - must be 11 digit long and only required for anyone with any of the following profiles user detail record:

```
Profile Name = Sales Agent,
Profile Name = Field Sales Agent,
Profile Name = Field Service Agent,
Profile Name = Lead Gen Agent,
Profile Name = Leade Gen Team Leader/Manager,
Profile Name = Sales Team Leader/Manager
Profile Name = TEL Sales Agent,
Profile Name = THS Sales Agent
```

Any other profiles e.g system admin or standard user would be able to save the user detail record without phone number filed required.

I have tried this:

```
AND(
   ISBLANK(Phone)
Profile.Name = "Sales Agent", 
OR(Profile.Name = ‘Field Sales Agent’),
OR(Profile.Name = ‘Field Service Agent’),
OR(Profile.Name = ‘Lead Gen Agent’),
OR(Profile.Name = ‘Lead Gen Team Leader/Manager’),
OR(Profile.Name = ‘Sales Team Leader/Manager’),
OR(Profile.Name = ‘TEL Sales Agent’),
OR(Profile.Name = ‘THS Sales Agent’)
)
)
```

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Hi, Thanks @Moonpie and @Caspar Harmer - that worked, appreciate it. I just now need to make sure the phone number always starts with 0 and is no more than 11 digits long as standard.
This is what I have so far which hasn't worked:

```
AND(
ISBLANK(Phone),
!REGEX(Phone, "^(0)[1-9]{1}([0-9]{8,9})$"),
Phone != 'unknown',
OR (Profile.Name = "Sales Agent",
Profile.Name = "Field Sales Agent",
Profile.Name = "Field Service Agent",
Profile.Name = "Lead Gen Agent",
Profile.Name = "Lead Gen Team Leader/Manager",
Profile.Name = "Sales Team Leader/Manager",
Profile.Name = "TEL Sales Agent",
Profile.Name = "THS Sales Agent")
)
```

Would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/350075/edit) your question to add the Validation Rule code which you have tried but that does not work.

Comment: It may just be a typo or transfer error, but the formula as posted is missing a `,` (comma) after `ISBLANK(Phone)`.

Comment: If you would like to edit this question, you will need to recover the account you used to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Added the phone part.

This is the syntax you'll need:

```
AND(
  Condition 1,
  OR (Condition 2,
      Condition 3,
      Condition 4)
)
```

In your case, it starts like this:

```
AND(
   OR(ISBLANK(Phone),
      NOT(REGEX(Phone, "^(0)[1-9]{1}([0-9]{8,9})$"))
   ),
   OR (Profile.Name = "Sales Agent",
       Profile.Name = "Field Sales Agent",
       Profile.Name = "Field Service Agent" 
   )
)
```

The rule must fire IF:

- The phone value is empty OR
- The phone value is the wrong format AND
- The profile is one of the following...

BTW, phone won't validate if 'unknown' so I don't think this is required.

Note how I've carefully formatted the functions - this makes it much easier to read and debug.

Comment: Since `OR` is the operator that the OP seems to be having the bigger issue with, I suggest you add the specific syntax for the `OR` similar to how you did for the `AND`.

Comment: Changed as per your suggestion - good idea!

Comment: @Caspar Harmer, thank you so much! That worked just need to now make it start with 0 and only 11 digits long. I've added what I have so far but doesn't quite work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moonpie!

Comment: @Caspar Harmer, worked! Thanks a lot! And yes, loved the formatting. Learnt a lot. Thanks for laying it out like that. Much appreciated.